# Cambiar URL´S y mostrar diferente contenido

Tags: javascript

Estoy extrayendo datos de varias cuentas de la api de twitter con Codebird, lo que necesito es únicamente cambiar el index por el hashtag correspondiente:

ejemplo: tengo un hashtag que se llama sttmed, otro que se llama TransitoBaq, necesito es que solamente cambie el hashtag en la url y se muestre el correspondiente, no se si me hago entender: Mi código:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>twitter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codebird.js"></script>

    <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="200;">

<style>
*{margin:0px;
    padding:0px;}
    
    #myVideo {
    position: relative;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%
    }
    #content-text {
    position: absolute;
    
    z-index:9999;
    font-size:47px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color:#9e9d9e;
    margin:0px 600px;
    margin-top:20px;
    top: 270px;
    left: 10px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    

<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="MovilidadCali.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="TransitoBaq.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div id="content-text"></div>

    <script>
    var cb = new Codebird;
    cb.setConsumerKey('pYz6237I1RQtX7AdyXwzuTPpd','bZGzPGMnE11dZ2Cdc0reDWMyQoLFdu3VLZm9W8FUy8xnVw7Qos');
    cb.setToken('1045064296714162176-aeOY3I2iKgymOzhWaXrbwQodctcfr5','Xs1aiRQ2RDwScUrm958qjHxy2p11aAGX4dsy2MrVBuIBL');

    var params = { 
        
    q: 'from:MovilidadCali AND -filter:retweets AND -filter:replies',
    q: 'from:TransitoBaq AND -filter:retweets AND -filter:replies',
    result_type: 'recent',
    count: 1
    
        
}; cb . __call ( "search_tweets" , params, function (reply) {
   // ... 
   document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = reply.statuses[0].text;
   var tmp = "/Users/juanpablo/Desktop/Piezas%20de%20twitter%20terminadas,%20por%20implementar%20en%20el%20sistema%20de%20carteleras%20/twitter-general/TransitoBaq.html".split('/');
    console.log(tmp[tmp.length-1].replace('.html','').replace('indexH_','').replace('indexV_','')) 

});

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿quieres modificar una URL sustituyendo dos partes por dos hashtags?

Comment: Mira esta es la url :file:///Users/juanpablo/Desktop/Piezas%20de%20twitter%20terminadas,%20por%20implementar%20en%20el%20sistema%20de%20carteleras%20/twitter-general/TransitoBaq.html y acá me sale el último tweet de transito barranquilla, entonces quiero que cuando ponga sttmed: que es la de movilidad de medellin solo tenga que modificar el archivo html per la misma url, no se si me hago entender.

Comment: Esto es con el fin de no tener un monton de index, sino modificar el hashtag y listo, porque la libreria que uso es la misma para todo, solo necesito modificar el hashtag.

Comment: ¿Dónde quieres poner sttmed? /sttmed.html ? ¿Es lo que intentas conseguir?

Comment: Exacto, y que se muestre la de Medellín.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como conversamos en los comentarios, para poder sustituir esa ruta por la nueva `sttmed.html` puedes hacer:

```js
let tmp = "/Users/juanpablo/Desktop/Piezas%20de%20twitter%20terminadas,%20por%20implementar%20en%20el%20sistema%20de%20carteleras%20/twitter-general/TransitoBaq.html";
let splitted = tmp.split("/");
splitted.pop()
tmp = splitted.join("/")+"/sttmed.html";

console.log(tmp);
```

Pero lo que te recomiendo es tener un path incompleto y entonces, en función de lo que quieres, añadir una opción u otra:

```js
let path = "/Users/juanpablo/Desktop/Piezas%20de%20twitter%20terminadas,%20por%20implementar%20en%20el%20sistema%20de%20carteleras%20/twitter-general/";

function transitoBaq() {
  let transitoBaq = path + "TransitoBaq.html";
  console.log(transitoBaq);
  return transitoBaq;
}

function sttmed() {
  let sttmed = path + "sttmed.html";
  console.log(sttmed);
  return sttmed;
}

transitoBaq();
sttmed();
```

Comment: Son conceptos básicos de JS, deberías estar mejor informado. Te puedo recomendar recursos para aprender o ayudarte (como hice en la respuesta) pero no solucionar en totalidad el problema.

Comment: Listo ya me funcionó, perfecta esa respuesta.